# How to initialize JS variables through Selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I am trying to execute a JS file through python, selenium but I think I miss something.

I tried to call the `checking` variable from safari console, but it shows the following error `Can't find the checking variable.`

I also tried to execute the following code line `driver.execute_script('var checking=0;')` but I got the same result when I tried to call the `checking` variable from Safari Console.

**PYTHON CODE**

```
driver.execute_script(open("/Users/Paul/Downloads/pythonProject/Social media/javascripts/Initializing Variables.js").read())
```

**JS FILE**

```
var checking;
function Checking(item) {
    if (item) {
        checking = true;
    }
    else {
        checking = false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables will be available just in single `execute_script` command context. So it's not possible to define variable in one driver command and modify it or get by another, unless you put the data to document, localstorage or sessionstorage..

But you're able to declare and put something to the variable, just don't forget to return it's value in script.

If I execute this script with `driver.execute_script`

```
var a;
function setAValue(arg) {
    a = arg;
}

setAValue(100);
return a;
```

you'll get 100 in the output result.

And if you want to run your file from script, the file should ends with the function invocation and the return statement.

**Share function and variables between scripts**

This is working example in groovy language (sorry no python env)

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
//define variable date and function GetTheDatesOfPosts 
driver.executeScript('''
    document.date = [];
    document.GetTheDatesOfPosts = function (item) { document.date = [item];}
''')

//use them in new script
println (driver.executeScript('''
    document.GetTheDatesOfPosts(7);
    return document.date;
    '''))
driver.quit()
```

it prints `[7]`.

Comment: Fair enough. so ```driver.execute_sript``` is running only local variables & functions. Am I right?

Comment: @PaulViorel it might run global functions too, and access global variables. E.g. access `ducument` or `window`. But you not able to define local variable by one script and access it with another script.

Comment: I declared my variable like that ```document.date = [];```  .Function like that ```document.GetTheDatesOfPosts = function (item) {//code} ``` and when I call this function I get the same error: ```Can't find variable: date```

Comment: @PaulViorel I was able to share the variable and function from your comment without errors, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, it was my bad... I had a typo, instead of ```document.``` I had ```docmnet.```.... So frustrating... Thank again

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick tutorial on local vs globally scoped variables.

If you run a command such as:

```py
self.execute_script("var xyz = 'abc';")
```

and then go to the console to try to find `xyz`, it won't be there (`xyz is not defined`).

However, if you run:

```py
self.execute_script("document.xyz = 'abc';")
```

then it will be in the browser console if you type `document.xyz`.

That's the short summary. If you just try to declare a local variable when run from `execute_script`, then it'll go out-of-scope after the script is run. However, if you attach a variable to a persistent one, that's one way of keeping the variable around (and still accessible).

Comment: ```if you attach a variable to a persistent one``` What does ```persistent one``` mean? I want to store also some functions to call them later from selenium.

Comment: Attaching a variable to ``document`` would make it persistent, so if you define ``document.myVariable = "ANYTHING;`` in the script, you'll be able to use it later. If you just define ``myVariable`` without the ``document``, then it would go out-of-scope after your script is called and it would not persist.

Comment: And is there any way to make a whole js file persistent? With a code line or something? Because I also have functions, and ```document.function X()``` or ```function document.X()``` doesn't work.

Comment: On the last line of your script file, add:
``document.Checking = Checking;`` (That brings over the function. Do a similar action for any variables that you want to carry over - put them in ``document``)